# Gvim rendering artifacts?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

I'm running Gvim 704 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64. Sometimes for some unapparent reason I get these blue dot artifacts:

[image]

I'm very minimalist when it comes to plugins, I only use pathogen, ctrlp, nerdcommenter, tabular, vim-scroll-smooth and vim-surround. I also have a dll that enables me to go fullscreen via F11.

If I do any activity like changing windows (give focus to another window and refocus on vim again), close/reopen the vim buffer/window, toggle fullscreen etc the artifacts go away. It updates its position in the screen as I scroll up/down.

Here's my vimrc:

```
behave mswin
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
let $PATH .= ';C:\Windows\SysWOW64'

""{{{ -- AutoCommands --

augroup FormatOptions
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter * setlocal formatoptions-=cro
augroup END
    "Start maximized
    augroup OnEnter
        autocmd!
        autocmd VimEnter * call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)
        autocmd GUIEnter * simalt ~x
    augroup END
    " Auto set working directory
    augroup UpdateCWD
        autocmd!
        autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
    augroup END
""}}}

""{{{ -- Misc Settings --

    " split chars
    set fillchars=stl:-
    set fillchars+=vert:\|

    " fixes some scrolling/rendering issues
    set ttyscroll=0
    set nocursorline
    set nocursorcolumn

    " switch cases indentation
    set cinoptions==0

    " global search/replace by default
    set gdefault

    " cursor shape
    set guicursor+=i:ver11
    set guicursor+=v:ver11
    set guicursor+=n:block

    " disable blinking
    set guicursor=a:blinkon0

    " these four speed things up when syn high is enabled and browsing huge amount of text
    syntax sync minlines=256

    set norelativenumber
    set expandtab
    set nocompatible
    set shellslash
    set backspace=2
    set guifont=Courier_New:h12:cANSI
    "set guifont=Consolas:b:h12:cANSI "use _ for spaces
    color black
    syntax on
    set wrap
    set autoindent
    set smartindent
    set tabstop=4
    set shiftwidth=4
    set textwidth=65
    set laststatus=0                " status line
    filetype plugin indent on
    set noswapfile
    set nobackup
    set nohlsearch
    "set hlsearch                   " highlights all the found instances in a search
    set ignorecase                  " Ignore case when searching
    set smartcase                   " Ignore case if search is all lowercase, case-sensitive otherwise.
    set incsearch                   " Show search matches as you type.
    scriptencoding utf-8            " UTF-8 encoding
    set guioptions=                 " no gui, whatsoever
    set autoread                    " auto read files after they're modified without displaying a prompt
    set mouse=a

""}}}

""{{{ -- Plugins --

    " Fullscreen
    map <F11> <Esc>:call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)<CR>

    "Tabularize
    nnoremap <leader>t= :Tabularize /=<cr>
    nnoremap <leader>t{ :Tabularize /{<cr>
    nnoremap <leader>t: :Tabularize /:<cr>
    vnoremap <leader>t= :Tabularize /=<cr>
    vnoremap <leader>t{ :Tabularize /{<cr>
    vnoremap <leader>t: :Tabularize /:<cr>

    "CtrlP"
        let g:ctrlp_root_markers = ['Source', 'src']

        set wildignore+=*\\tmp\\*,*.swp,*.zip,*.exe,*.meta,*.mat,*.suo,*.csproj,*.sln,*.dwlt,
                        \*.asset,*.unity,*.db,*.xml,*.cache,*.prefab,*.fbx,*.max,*.lxo,*.blend,
                        \*.obj,*.3DS,*.smd,*.mp3,*.ogg,*.wav,*.png,*.jpg,*.prefs,*.anim,*.unityproj,
                        \*.config,*.log,*.rsp,
                        \*UnityTempFile*,*.pdb,*.dll,*.ilk,*.lnk,*.ini

        nnoremap <C-m><c-p> :CtrlPMRU<cr>

        let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
          \ 'dir':  '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$',
          \ 'file': '\v\.(exe|so|dll|meta)$',
          \ 'link': 'some_bad_symbolic_links',
          \ }

    "UltiSnips"
        " Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
        let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<s-tab>"
        let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-k>"
        let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-i>"

        " If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
        let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"

    "Smooth scroll"
        noremap <silent> <c-f> m':call smooth_scroll#down(&scroll * 1, 1, 2)<CR>
        noremap <silent> <c-a> m':call smooth_scroll#up(&scroll * 1, 1, 2)<CR>

    "Pathogen"
        let g:pathogen_disabled = []
        execute pathogen#infect()
""}}}

""{{{ -- Mappings

    "collapse blocks of empty lines into a single one
    nnoremap <silent> <leader>re ma:%s/^\_s\+\n/\r<CR>'azz

    "unicode insertion
    inoremap <C-k> <C-v>
    cnoremap <C-k> <C-v>

    "member search (works only when lines start with member names)
    nnoremap <A-/> /^

    "indent block
    nnoremap + =}
    nnoremap =i =i{

    "find variable/function declaration (works when their name is the start of the line)
    nnoremap <A-d> yiw/^\<<C-R>"\><CR>zz
    "find struct/class/enum
    nnoremap <A-f><A-s> yiw/^\<struct <C-R>"\><CR>zz
    nnoremap <A-f><A-c> yiw/^\<class <C-R>"\><CR>zz
    nnoremap <A-f><A-e> yiw/^\<enum <C-R>"\><CR>zz

    "simple for loop template
    "inoremap ,for <C-O>m'for(; ;)<CR>{<CR>}<C-O>''<Esc>m'=i{''f(a

    "double toggle fullscreen
    nmap <leader>ff <F11><F11>

    "jump to end of file
    nnoremap <Space> G
    vnoremap <Space> G

    "serach for visually selected text
    vnoremap * y/<C-R>"<CR>
    vnoremap # y?<C-R>"<CR>

    "Jump list
    "forward
    nnoremap <S-o> <C-I>

    "Rename" (whole word)
    "current line
    nnoremap <A-r><A-r> :s/\<<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>\>//I<left><left>
    "current function scope
    nmap <A-r><A-l> Y[mV%:s/\<<C-R>"\>//cI<left><left><left>
    "global
    nnoremap <A-r><A-g> :%s/\<<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>\>//cI<left><left><left>

    nnoremap gr gd[{V%::s/<C-R>///cI<left><left><left>
    nnoremap gR gD:%s/<C-R>///cI<left><left><left>

    "Essential"
        " Leader
        let mapleader = ","
        " Quick vimrc edit
        nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC <cr>
        " Quick vimrc reload (sourcing)
        nnoremap <leader>so :source $MYVIMRC <Bar>nohlsearch<cr>
        " Clear search
        nnoremap <silent><A-c> :nohlsearch<Return>
        inoremap <silent><A-c> <esc>:nohlsearch<Return>a
        " Quick insert/normal modes toggle (Caps is mapped to F2 via ahk)
        nnoremap <F2> i
        inoremap <silent><F2> <Esc>:call GoRightIfNotBOL()<CR>
        vnoremap <F2> <Esc>

    "Misc Nops
        nnoremap <A-f> <Nop>
        " mouse nops
        map <MiddleMouse> <Nop>

    "Movement"   
        noremap k gj
        noremap i gk
        noremap j h
        " Next/prev word (insert mode)
        inoremap <C-l> <esc>ea
        inoremap <C-j> <esc>bi
        " Jump to last cursor position
        nnoremap <A--> ``
        " Navigation
        "next/prev word/block
        nnoremap J b
        nnoremap L w
        "nnoremap I {
        "nnoremap K }
        vnoremap J b
        vnoremap L w
        "vnoremap I {
        "vnoremap K }   

        nnoremap / :set hlsearch<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>/
        nnoremap ? :set hlsearch<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>?

        nnoremap <silent> I :set nohlsearch<CR>?^\s*$<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
        nnoremap <silent> K :set nohlsearch<CR>/^\s*$<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
        vnoremap <silent> I ?^\s*$<CR>
        vnoremap <silent> K /^\s*$<CR>

        "next/prev method/function'
        nnoremap <silent>} /^{<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
        nnoremap <silent>{ ?^{<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>

        "beginning/end of line
        nnoremap m ox<BS>
        nnoremap o Ox<BS>
        "nnoremap m o
        "nnoremap o O
        nnoremap h ^i
        nnoremap ' $a
        vnoremap h ^
        vnoremap ' $

        "jump to top/middle/bottom of the screen
        nnoremap <S-h> M
        nnoremap <S-t> H
        nnoremap <S-b> L
        vnoremap <S-h> M
        vnoremap <S-t> H
        vnoremap <S-b> L

        " jump to match
        nnoremap <S-m> %
        vnoremap <S-m> %

        "Scroll screen 'without' moving cursor
        "one char
        nnoremap <C-i> <C-y>
        nnoremap <C-k> <C-e>
        nnoremap <C-j> zh
        nnoremap <C-l> zl
        vnoremap <C-i> <C-y>
        vnoremap <C-k> <C-e>
        vnoremap <C-j> zh
        vnoremap <C-l> zl

        "screen
        nnoremap <C-h> zz
        nnoremap <C-t> zt
        nnoremap <C-b> zb
        vnoremap <C-h> zz
        vnoremap <C-t> zt
        vnoremap <C-b> zb

    "Clipboard"
        " Undoing
        nnoremap <C-z> u
        inoremap <C-z> <C-[>ui
        " This is due to the fact that in VS, Ctrl-V is reserved for paste
        nnoremap <A-v> <C-v>

    "Other"
        " yank current word
        nnoremap Y yiw

        " For recording purposes, fast repeating.
        nnoremap <A-2> @a

        " Change inside
        nnoremap <A-i> ci
        nnoremap <A-i><A-'> ci"
        nnoremap <A-i><A-9> ci(

        " Join
        nnoremap <A-j> J
        vnoremap <A-j> J

        " Visual->insert
        vnoremap <A-i> I
        vnoremap <A-a> A

        " Jumps cursor inside braces http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621173/vim-and-indentation-with-brackets-braces
        inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>O

    "Visual/Select"
        " Visually select the current word
        nnoremap v<space> viw

    "Numerics"
        " [de-in]crement
        nnoremap <A-a> <C-a>
        nnoremap <A-x> <C-x>

    "Deletion"
        " Delete word under cursor
        nnoremap d<space> diw
        nnoremap c<space> ciw
        " delete word to the left of cursor.
        inoremap <C-BS> <C-W>
        " Enhanced change line
        nnoremap <silent>cc :call ChangeCurrentLine()<cr>a

    "GUI"
        " Toggle menu bar
        nnoremap <silent><leader>tm :call ToggleMenuBar()<cr>

    "Buffers"
        " previous buffer
        nnoremap <leader>3 :buf #<CR>

        " Show a menu to complete buffer and file names
        set wildchar=<Tab> wildmenu wildmode=full"

        " Writing/saving
        inoremap <C-s> <C-[>:w <Enter>a
        nnoremap <C-s> :w <Enter>

        " To open a new empty buffer
        nnoremap <leader>T :enew<cr>

        " Move to the next buffer
        nnoremap <leader>l :bnext<CR>

        " Move to the previous buffer
        nnoremap <leader>j :bprevious<CR>

        " Close the current buffer and move to the previous one
        " This replicates the idea of closing a tab
        nnoremap <leader>bq :bp <BAR> bd #<CR>

        " Show all open buffers and their status
        nnoremap <leader>bl :ls<CR>

    "Windows"
        " Switching windows
        nnoremap <silent> <leader>wi :wincmd k<CR>
        nnoremap <silent> <leader>wk :wincmd j<CR>
        nnoremap <silent> <leader>wj :wincmd h<CR>
        nnoremap <silent> <leader>wl :wincmd l<CR>
        " Resizing
        nnoremap <silent><A-S-l> :15winc ><CR>
        nnoremap <silent><A-S-j> :15winc <<CR>
        nnoremap <silent><A-S-i> <C-w>5+
        nnoremap <silent><A-S-k> <C-w>5-
        " Veritcal Split
        nnoremap <leader>sv <C-w>v
""}}}

""{{{ -- Functions --
    function! ToggleMenuBar()
        let &g:guioptions = ToggleStringValue(&g:guioptions, "m")
    endfu

    function! IsLineEmpty(line)
        return match(a:line, '^\s*$') == -1 ? 0 : 1
    endfu

    function! IsCurrentLineEmpty()
        return IsLineEmpty(getline('.'))
    endfu

    function! ChangeCurrentLine()
        execute "normal! " . (IsCurrentLineEmpty() ? "0" : "^") . "C"
    endfu

    " Returns 1 if the cursor is at the beginning of a line "
    function! IsBOL()
        return col('.') == 1
    endfu

  function! GoRightIfNotBOL()
        if !IsBOL()
            execute "normal l"
        endif
    endfu

    function! ToggleStringValue(input, value)
        let l:result = a:input
        if l:result =~ a:value
            let l:result = substitute(l:result, a:value, "", "")
        else
            let l:result .= a:value
        endif
        return l:result
    endfu

    function! s:JumpMethod(char, flags, mode)
        let original_cursor = getpos('.')

        if a:mode == 'v'
            normal! gv
        elseif a:mode == 'o'
            normal! v
        endif

        while search(a:char, a:flags) > 0
            if a:char == '}'
                " jump to the opening one to analyze the definition
                normal! %
            endif

            let current_line = line('.')

            if getline(current_line) =~ '^\s*{'
                " it's alone on the line, check the above one
                let method_line = current_line - 1
            else
                let method_line = current_line
            endif

            let method_line_body = getline(method_line)

            if method_line_body =~ '\k\+\s*(.*)' && method_line_body !~ '\<\(for\|foreach\|if\|while\|switch\|using\|catch\|get\|set\)\>'
                " it's probably a function call

                if a:char == '}'
                    " we need to go back to the closing bracket
                    normal! %
                endif

                echo
                return
            else
                if a:char == '}'
                    " we still need to go back to the closing bracket
                    normal! %
                endif
            endif
        endwhile

        " if we're here, the search has failed, restore cursor position
        echo
        call setpos('.', original_cursor)
    endfunction
""}}}
```

I never had these issues before but I vaguely remember starting to have them around the time I added the ilnes:

```
set ttyscroll=0
set nocursorline
set nocursorcolumn

syntax sync minlines=256
```

I'm not exactly sure they're related but I do remember adding them was an attempt to solve the rendering/artifacts problems. The artifacts don't happen in a replicate-able manner so even if I were to disable those options I might not see any immediately but eventually do.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how to get rid of it?

Comment: can you try http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/1821 and le us know if this issues is related to your vimrc ?

Comment: Does it happen with another font? One that has italic and bold also installed.

Comment: Well I commented out the lines I was suspicious about and used another font "Input Mono", earlier I was using "Courier_New". So far it's not happening, and scrolling is a bit faster BUT there is this common jitter/flicker that happens when I scroll via C-y/C-e (single line scroll) and not page up/down.

Comment: Try also to enable directx rendering: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3j6wbv/starting_to_use_vim_at_work_and_home_but_i_have/cuna9h0

Comment: Not sure that line is getting executed. The if is executed if my vim version is higher than 704 (which it isn't) or of if is 704 (true) and has patch393 (false). Setting the render mode directly without those if checks vim errors out, "Unknown command". `:h renderoptions` shows no help for renderoptions.

Comment: You *could* install a more recent Vim ...

Comment: I don't think there is a more recent version than 7.4 (704) is there?

Comment: Yes, 7.4 with all the patches written from its release until now ... http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/README

Comment: Is there a way to get an updated binary/build? Downloading from the main site the latest updated build is Jul 2013. Some of the patches you showed contain very recent updates. Am I supposed to compile the source? or..? [Edit] it seems that vim has finally moved to github!

Comment: Yes. I recommend [this one](http://www.kaoriya.net/software/vim/) - the "Win 64bit" link. After extraction, remove the 'vimrc' and 'gvimrc' files from the main folder. Alternatively, there is https://bintray.com/veegee/generic/vim_x64/

Comment: Thanks for your help. My AV is flagging the exe from the latter link. The first link works. I ended up using the 32 bit cause it was the only version I was able to find a working gvimfullscreen dll (https://github.com/derekmcloughlin/gvimfullscreen_win32/tree/master), it's really silly to have to go through all this to get a working gvim binary with fullscreen. There's one that works with the 64bit version but has those annoying white borders https://github.com/xqin/gvimfullscreen if you happen to know a flawless way of fullscreen that works in x64 I'd appreciate it

Comment: This might work, has both dlls included: https://github.com/xolox/vim-shell (needs https://github.com/xolox/vim-misc as dependency). Although I remember it still might have the white borders.